# Google App Script not sending auto Email via Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I have been trying to send auto Email through Google App-script. There are two similar scripts but have two different

**Email Text**
**Email Body**
**Subject**

I have also set a trigger to send Auto Email on edit and the script is send the Email when there is "**Different**" value in **Col"E"**. (Script name is 2nd_Email)

I just want that if "**New Request**" value is come in **Col"E"** then **1st_Email** script should follow.

I have tried at my end but sometimes 1st_Email scripts works and sometimes 2nd_Email works.

I want both of them to work according to Col"E" values.

Please visit the sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eu-c5CPj6XKQSAkSumuprA41-Cx_jvOuUPHr9Zg8KyQ/edit#gid=797418690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the trigger only for the `First_email` function and add the second code to your first one as an alternative to your if condition.

```
function First_email() { 

  var INITIALline = 2; 
  var columnSEND = 5;  
  var STATUScolumn = 16;
  var textCONDITION = "New Request";
  var textCONDITION2 = "Different";
  var textSENT = "Mail_Sent"
    
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data"); 
  var interval = tab.getRange(INITIALline,1,tab.getLastRow()-INITIALline+1,STATUScolumn);
  var dice = interval.getValues();
  var yousent = false;
  var email,subject,message;
  
  for (var i=0; i<dice.length; ++i) {
    if((dice[i][columnSEND-1]==textCONDITION) && (dice[i][STATUScolumn-1]!=textSENT)){
    
      var email    = dice[i][9]
    
      subject = dice[i][6]+" | New Request | "+dice[i][0];
            
      var message = "<font size='3' face='Comfortaa'>Dear Different "+dice[i][6]+",<br/><br/>"+
      
                     "Thanks for New Request with us."+dice[i][0]+".<br/><br/>"+
                     
                     "<i>Thanks & Regards</i><br/>"+
                     "<b> New Request </b>";
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message,{ htmlBody: message});
      tab.getRange(INITIALline+i,STATUScolumn).setValue(textSENT);
      yousent = true;
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    
     else if((dice[i][columnSEND-1]==textCONDITION2) && (dice[i][STATUScolumn-1]!=textSENT)){
    
      var email    = dice[i][9]
    
      subject = dice[i][6]+" | Different | "+dice[i][0];
            
      var message = "<font size='3' face='Comfortaa'>Dear "+dice[i][6]+",<br/><br/>"+
      
                     "Thanks for Different with us."+dice[i][0]+".<br/><br/>"+
                     
                     "<i>Thanks & Regards</i><br/>"+
                     "<b> Different </b>";
      
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message,{ htmlBody: message});
      tab.getRange(INITIALline+i,STATUScolumn).setValue(textSENT);
      yousent = true;
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
     
  }
 }
```